# Mi Update en Java, no quiere actualizar los datos

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy intentando actualizar un valor en MySql, mediante una vista en NetBeans, el código funciona, y me muestra el mensaje de "Factura actualizada", pero al mirar los datos en la base de datos, me doy cuenta que no se actualizo, el código no me manda ningún error.

```
    String codigof;
     int valorA, valorB;
     
    try {
        
        String sql = "UPDATE facturas SET total_pagar = ? WHERE ID_U = ?";
       //stmt = con.con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement st = con.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        
       if(table.getRowCount()==1){
     
      for(int i =0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
         codigof = String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i,0));
         valorA = Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(i,2).toString());
         
         valorB = (int) (valorA*0.10)+valorA;
         table.setValueAt(valorB, i, 2);
         st.setString(1, String.valueOf(valorB));
         st.setString(2,codigof);
     }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La factura ha sido actualizada.");
   }
```

Comment: Yo creo que no es Java quien no quiere hacerlo... de hecho, me parece que eres tú quien no quiere hacerlo. Porque creas un prepareStatement, pero nunca lo *ejecutas*. Java es muy listo, pero no va a hacer nada que tú no le pidas. Por cierto, si se cumple el if, es decir, `getRowCount()==1`, no tiene sentido un `for`, puesto que ... solo hay UNA (1) fila!

Answer (score 1):

No estás ejecutando la actualización con [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--). Lo debes poner al final de los `set...`, por ejemplo:

```
     st.setString(1, String.valueOf(valorB));
     st.setString(2,codigof);
     //Sin esta llamada la actualización no ocurrirá nunca
     st.executeUpdate();
```

### Recomendación

Viendo que estás ejecutando actualizaciones dentro de un bucle, te recomendaría que uses transacciones para tu código, así podrás revertir los cambios si algo falla. En actualizaciones masivas puede ser complicado verificar a posteriori cuáles datos fueron actualizados y cuáles no en caso de ocurrir algún error.

Para más detalles consulta el [tutorial sobre PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).